# Qt Connect Event to non-QObject Types

Tags: c++, qt, events, event-handling, qt5

I have a data model object, with a method intended to handle Qt events.  However, when I attempt to connect an event handlers to this method, I get a compile-time error.  The issue is that the `connect` template eventually performs a `static_cast<void (QObject::*)(double)>` on the fourth argument.  Since my data model doesn't inherit from `QObject`, this code generates error C2664:

> Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Is there a way to connect event handlers to non-QObject types?  A minimal example:

```
struct DataModel {
    void handle(double) { }
};

DataModel data;
QDoubleSpinBox spinBox;
connect(&spinBox, QOverload<double>::of(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
    &data, &DataModel::handle);
```

This type requirement seems unnecessary given that all the "connect" method does is setup event forwarding.  Is there a reason why we can't use any valid function pointer there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the new connection options available since Qt 5 is the use of lambda as *slots*, very useful in these situations:

```
// adapt the capture to your specific situation
connect(&spinBox, qOverload<double>(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
       [&data](double arg) { data.handle(arg); });
```

PS: I've used a shorter form to choose the correct overload, that you may find useful: [`qOverload<double>(...)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload).

Comment: This is functionally identical to the answer I came up with, but more concise due to the use of a lambda instead of `std::bind`.  I couldn't get the shorter `qOverload` form to work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is another connect template overload that takes any kind of function object.  Therefore, I was able to rewrite my `connect` method call as:

```
connect(&spinBox, QOverload<double>::of(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
    std::bind(std::mem_fn(&DataModel::handle), &data, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Then Qt doesn't attempt to cast anything to an incompatible type.